# Вёрстка на Bootstrap подсветка только текста

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемкой:
При наведении не пропадает задний фон, т.е мне нужно что бы подсвечивался только текст.
Верстаю на bootstrap 3, (bootstrap.css)
Заранее спасибо!
[image: Скриншот с косяком]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper a">
            <div class="left-sidebar a">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Турниры</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Лиги</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Рейтинг</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Фортуна</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Видео</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Техподдержка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ЧАВО</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "наведении не пропадает задний фон" — это фактическое поведение или ожидаемое?

Answer (score 1):

Решилось вот так:
Просто нужно было добавить кое какие DIV, CSS тут оказался не причём.

[image: Решение]

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left col-lg-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="#">Турниры</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Лиги</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Рейтинг</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Фортуна</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Видео</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Техподдержка</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ЧАВО</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать `li:hover {background: нужный цвет;}` в файле с css.

Comment: А что если будет вместо текста например картинка? Сделать параметр null?

Comment: По сути всё должно происходить так же, нужно проверить.

Comment: К сожалению данный вариант не сработал...

Answer (score 0):

```
nav li:hover {
  background: #202D3B !important;
}
```